# Redirect to External URl in Spring MVC by RequestMethod.POST

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I will redirect to external url from spring controller, and this action must be POST type.

my controller :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/purchase", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView purchase(@RequestParam(value = "RefId", required = true) String RefId){
 String url="https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/startpay.mellat?RefId=" + refId;
                RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
                redirectView.setUrl(url);

                return new ModelAndView(redirectView);
```

}

I should have created POST request but this action in GET.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedirectView class has created GET action and it can't POST request.

I put refId in ModelMap object and redirect to jsp.

```
   map.put("refId", refId);
```

So when page loaded then create post request form submit.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      if (${not empty refId}) {
          var refId = ('${refId}');
          document.getElementById('bank-card-form').action = 'https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/startpay.mellat?RefId=' + refId;
          document.getElementById('bank-card-form').submit();

    }
   });
```

And in my jsp added bank-card-form

```
 <form method="post" id="bank-card-form"
      style="display: none" autocomplete="off">
  </form>
```